# Notice: Undefined index: dateform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, post

i have created two calender datepicker and i am trying to get the input data or get the "post" date, but when i try to run my code i am getting this error, Notice: **Undefined index: dateform**

I do not have any idea why i am getting this error, because i have declear in my html that the value will be **post** type, so why it is saying the vaue is undefined, any one knows how to solve this prblem. Thanks a lot in advanced.

**html code --**

```
<form>
  <div action = "/userpage/dateform" method="post" id="datepicker">

<input type="text" name="dateform" id="dateform" class="span2 datepicker" placeholder="From...">

<input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto" class="span2 datepicker" placeholder="To...">
<div id="datesearch"></div>

<input type="submit" name="dateSearch" value="Search" class="btn">
</div>
  </form>
```

**Script code ---**

```
<script>
    var datf = $("#dateform").val();
    var datt = $("#dateto").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/userpage/dateform",
  data: datf,datt,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $("#datesearch").text(data);
  }
});  
</script>
```

**php/ controller code ---**

```
public function dateformAction(){

        $from_date = strtotime($_POST['dateform']);
        $to_date = strtotime($_POST['dateto']);
```

error message --
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your ajax method is `GET` but you are checking for a `POST` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify on your form what type of request it is so either `GET` or `POST`. Yet you use `$_POST['dateform']`.

You need to make your `AJAX` request a `POST` to send variables and use them with `$_POST`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/userpage/dateform",
    data: {
      "dateForm" : datf,
      "yourKeyNameHere" : datt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       $("#datesearch").text(data);
    }
});
```

You had a couple of issues:

1. You were using `$_POST` when the `AJAX` request specified `$_GET`.
2. You had a trailing `,` after when you specified your `data`.
3. This may not be an error, but you never specified the keys for your `data`. ***AFAIK*** you have to specify a key to use the variable.

**Edit 1**

Please check if your *dateform* variable is actually set. As that could be causing the issue too.

**Edit 2**

This is most likely the issue. Your `url` property seems incorrect.

```
url: "/userpage/dateform",
```

You need to set you file extension.

If you fix the above all, it should *hopefully* fix your script.

Comment: thanks for your great answer, but still it is the same result :)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: dateform

Comment: syntaxError: missing } after property list
 
cache: false,

Comment: @IsakJohnsson is `datf` actually set?

Comment: yes i believe so, and i have posted all the code :)

Comment: @IsakJohnsson If you do a simple console output, does it show?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 

cache: false,

Comment: Is your `DOM` loaded?

Comment: I think so, cause i have other functions from elastic search which is working fine :)

Comment: @IsakJohnsson check **Edit 2**. This will probably fix.

Comment: @IsakJohnsson glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change  inside your ajax call

```
type: "POST",
data:{dateform:datf,dateto:datt},
```